# Return the value if the value exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails, is there a better way to write this:

```
qty = 2
avg_price = room["price"].to_f if room["price"].present?
total_price = (avg_price * qty) if avg_price.present?
```

Especially the 2nd and 3rd line. I find myself using the if-else condition too often. Thanks.

Comment: You want them to be `nil` when they are not `present?`? Or, could they be `0` or `0.0`?

Comment: @sawa, yeah it should be nil if not present.

Comment: Do you actually have values like `""` as a possibility? If not, you don't need `present?`. Especially, you clearly do not need it in the third line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
qty = 2
total_price = room.fetch("price").to_f * qty
```

But there is a problem with this code, if there is no `price` field in the hash, it will raise an exception. Does it suffice your needs ?

Comment: I need it to return nil. Can't raise exception.

Comment: Another approach - rescue it, setting the total_price as nil =)

    rescue
      total_price = nil

Comment: Thanks, but this is used in view. Don't want too many logics in the view.

Comment: or, you can go: total_price = room["price"] ? hash["price"].to_f*qty : nil

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to make this shorter, I would just do:

```
qty, avg_price, total_price = 2, nil, nil

if room["price"]
  avg_price   = Float(room["price"])
  total_price = avg_price * qty
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about defining a helper method so that you can directly extract a float from a hash:

```
class Hash
  def get_f key; fetch(key).to_f if key?(key) end # Or `if self[key].present?`
end
```

and then do:

```
qty = 2
avg_price = room.get_f("price")
total_price = avg_price * qty if avg_price
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more object oriented approach? This approach makes it easier to test the code and might be reuseable.

```
class PriceCalculator

  def init(quantity, price)
    @quantity = quantity
    @price    = price.presence && price.to_f
  end

  def total
    @price * @quantity  if @price
  end

end

total_price = PriceCalculator.new(2, room["price"]).total
```